# Analog Ramda.pathOr in lodash library

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

What is method equal [ramda.pathOr](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pathOr) in lodash library?

```
R.pathOr('N/A', ['a', 'b'], {a: {b: 2}}); //=> 2
R.pathOr('N/A', ['a', 'b'], {c: {b: 2}}); //=> "N/A"
```

How I can write this lodash syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) and hand over object, path and an optional default value.

```js
var value = _.get({ a: { b: 2 } }, ['a', 'b'], 'N/A');

console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.get()` already has an optional default value: `var value = _.get({ a: { b: 2 } }, ['a', 'b'], 'N/A')`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using lodash's `get` as per Nina's answer, the `getOr` function in lodash/fp has argument order and currying similar to Ramda:

```js
const {getOr} = require('lodash/fp');
getOr('N/A', ['a', 'b'], { a: { b: 2 } } );   // 2
getOr('N/A', ['a', 'b'])({ c: { b: 2 } } );   // 'N/A'
```

See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide, or for an example the answer at [How lodash / fp getOr works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502616/how-lodash-fp-getor-works) .