# How lodash / fp getOr works

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
import { getOr } from 'lodash/fp';
```

I would like to know how getOr works, because I was unable to find specific documentation to explain it.

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide

Comment: But the [github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) didn't mention how to use the arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `getOr()` method behaves in a very similar way to the regular [get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) method in the non-functional lodash library:

```
_.get(object, path, [defaultValue])
```

The above is the usage for `get` in regular lodash. To use it, you need to provide the `object` you want to grab the value from, the `path` to the value, and an optional `defaultValue` if the path doesn't exist within the object.

#### How to use `getOr()`:

The following is the usage for `_.getOr()`:

```
_.getOr(defaultValue)(path)(object)
```

Much like `_.get()` from regular lodash, the above returns the value located at `path` in `object`, or the `defaultValue` if the path does not exist within the object.

You may have noticed that you must provide a `defaultValue` above in order to pass the object and the path arguments. If you're certain your path will always lead to a value (and don't need a default value) then that's what the `_.get(path)(object)` method is for.

#### Example usage:

```js
const {getOr} = _;
const object = {'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }]};
console.log(getOr("default")("a[0].b.c")(object)); // 3
console.log(getOr("default")(['a', '0', 'b', 'c'])(object)); // 3
console.log(getOr("default")("a.b.c")(object)); // "default"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

#### How it works:

The definition for `_.getOr()` wraps the regular lodash `_.get()` definition, except that it is curried, the arguments are flipped, and the default value has to be supplied (as you wouldn't be able to supply the other curried arguments if you didn't provide the default value). Using lodash, you could implement `_.getOr` yourself like so:

```js
const {get, rearg, ary, curry} = _; // normal get method
const getOr = curry(rearg(ary(get), [2, 1, 0]));

const object = {'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }]};
console.log(getOr("default")("a[0].b.c")(object)); // 3
console.log(getOr("default")(['a', '0', 'b', 'c'])(object)); // 3
console.log(getOr("default")("a.b.c")(object)); // "default"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why not just use: `object.a[0].b.c` ?

Comment: @itsazzad Sometimes the property path you want to access is a string/dynamic eg: `"a[0].b.c"`, that's where this `getOr` method can be useful (as `object["a[0].b.c"]` won't work), otherwise, if you know that property path at the time of writing your code, using something like `object.a[0].b.c ?? "default"` is fine.